# add number in session not valid

Tags: php, session

index.php

```
<?php
session_start();
var_dump($_SESSION);
if (!isset($_SESSION['count'])) {
    $_SESSION['count'] = 0;
} else {
    $_SESSION['count'] += 1;
}

var_dump($_SESSION);
?>
```

What I want to do is store a number in the session, when I reload the page, print the session and add one to the number.

The problem: "add one" seems executed two times when one reload; 
one reload

```
array(1) { ["count"]=> int(3) } array(1) { ["count"]=> int(4) }
```

```
$ cat sess_xxxxx
count|i:5;
```

why the number store in the session become 5, the last var_dump in the page is 4?

The web Server I use is Nginx.

Comment: What do you get when you reload the page again - is it 4 & 5 now, or 5 & 6 already?

Comment: @04FS reload print is 6

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php  

session_start(); 

if(isset($_SESSION['count'])) 
    $_SESSION['count'] = $_SESSION['count']+1; 
else
    $_SESSION['count']=1; 

echo "views = ".$_SESSION['count']; 

?>
```

**Explanation**

**session_start() :** It is a first step which is used to start the session.

**$_SESSION['count']** :This is the session variable which is used to store views count for a user’s session.

**isset()** : It is a standard php function which returns true or false depending upon whether the passed parameter is set or not.

**Update** :

```
<?php

print_r($_SESSION);

session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['count'])) {
    $_SESSION['count'] = $_SESSION['count'] + 1;

} else {
    $_SESSION['count'] = 0;
}

?>
```

Comment: Just check is there any other redirection

Comment: Instead of `$_SESSION['count'] = $_SESSION['count'] + 1;` you could do `$_SESSION['count']++;`

Comment: @OliverNybo yes both are doing same. actually this will be more generalise so understand easily.

Comment: @VasimShaikh that is true, just thought I would mention it.

Answer (score 0):

I had request the /index.php twice;

The request to http://mywebstie, default send two request "GET /" and "GET /favicon.ico", and My web server Nginx config:

```
location / { 
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}
```

the "GET /favicon.ico" is redirect to /index.php。
So the page were reload twice, and the "add one" be executed twice.